# Modify individual namespace names in Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, namespaces, visual-c#-express-2010

I recently organized the classes in my project into folders and would like to have the namespaces of the classes renamed according to their folders. I have tried to rename them using 'Rename' (F2) but the compiler throws errors at me (even after rebuilding the solution). What would be the best way to do this? As the title states, I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express.

EDIT: I'd like to know how to do this manually in case I need to modify namespaces beyond a month from now. Resharper looks very nice, but I couldn't justify buying it at this point. Also, why the downvotes to my question?

EDIT: Is there really nobody who can tell me how to do this? Or at least tell me it's more trouble than it's worth? Or a workaround of sorts? Anything at all?

Comment: Was my answer helpul? If so, accept it so others can use it as well. If it wasn't, did you find a different solution to your problem?

Comment: If ReSharper were free (or even just cheaper than $150), your answer would have certainly been helpful. I was looking for something that would suit my needs for more than 30 days as I currently have a very limited income. I ended up just changing everything manually, though.

Comment: It's a shame, if your refactoring is a 1 time thing (I don't geuss you need to refactor your namespaces every month) then using the free trial of resharper would of solved it for you (instead of doing it manualy, there is a smaller chance resharper will miss something)

Answer (score 0):

You can always install ReSharper by JetBrains:
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/

They have a trial that works well for about a month, it can accomplish exactly what you want by right clicking anywhere and selecting "Adjust Namespaces", it will do the needed refactoring and you might find it to be a great tool to buy.